# Action delegate sending null value in mvvm wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This below code is for my ButtonCommand

```
class ButtonCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> whatToExecute;



    public ButtonCommand(Action<object> whatToExecute)
    {
        this.whatToExecute = whatToExecute;

    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //parameter have value          
        whatToExecute(parameter);

    }
}
```

And this below code is for my PersonViewModel in this class i get data from view and calling delegate that connect to Insert Method and Delete method and pass them to the ButtonCommand class:

```
PersonType personType;
    private ButtonCommand insertCommand;
    private ButtonCommand deleteCommand;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PersonTypeViewModel()
    {
        personType = new PersonType();
        insertCommand = new ButtonCommand((p)=> { Insert(PersonType); });
        deleteCommand = new ButtonCommand((s) => { Delete(PersonType); });
    }

    public ICommand btnClickInsert
    {
        get
        {
            return insertCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand btnClickDelete
    {
        get
        {
            return deleteCommand;
        }
    }
    public void Insert(PersonType personType)
    {            
        if(this.personType.Insert(personType) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull Insert");
        }
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GetAll"));
    }

    public List<PersonType> GetAll
    {
        get
        {
            return personType.GetAll();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(PersonType personType)
    {
        if (this.personType.Delete(personType) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull Delete");
        }
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GetAll"));
    }
```

this code is for my PersonType:

```
public PersonType()
   {
    int id { get; set; }
    string typeName { get; set; }
    string description { get; set; }
   }
```

in Insert method and Delete method personType values is null
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is `PersonType` in `Insert(PersonType)` and `Delete(PersonType)` supposed to be? Is there a property `PersonType`?

Comment: it's class for my data,this question is so amatory

Comment: But it won't compile... ?

Comment: Please show us the code from where the commands insertCommand/deleteCommand are called?

Comment: PersonTypeViewModel constructor